# ActiveRecord find parent based on non-existent child

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Suppose there is Material with has_many relationship with AttributeType. I can find the Parent of Children which name is equal to "abc". I want to find the Parent which does not contain a Child whose name is equal to "abc". I've already tried something like this:

```
attribute_types = @place.materials.collect(&:attribute_types).flatten.select{|at| at.name != "abc"}.flatten
```

but since it only does not pick up the child with the name "abc", it still gets the siblings. So when I use:

```
materials = @place.materials.where(id: attribute_types.map(&:material)).uniq
```

It still gets the record that I don't need.

What I'm looking for is when a several materials has attribute_types 'abc', 'def' and 'ghi', I want to look for the material that doesn't have 'abc'.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show us the relevant parts of your model definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the other answers/comments I deduce you do not only want to find the materials linked to an attribute that is not called 'abc' but also exclude the materials that have a link to attribute `abc`.

First find all materials having an attribute abc

```
materials_with_abc = @place.materials.joins(:attribute_types)
                                     .where(attribute_types: {name: 'abc'})
```

Then find all materials not linked to abc is then pretty easy

```
@place.materials.where.not(id: materials_with_abs.select(:id))
```

(I wrote it with map first, which is sub-optimal to say the least, but thanks to the tip from @enigineersmnky this generates a single query and is executed completely in the database and very efficient. No need to hand-code sql either!)

Comment: I would not recommend the `map` call here `materials_with_abs.map{|m| m.id }` this can be handled without the need to iterate using `select` which will create a sub-query rather than a potentially enormous list. e.g. `@place.materials.where.not(id: materials_with_abc.select(:id))`. This avoids your fetch first concern

Comment: OMG that is an awesome suggestion! Thanks!!